# Error compiling servlet: file not found

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile a `servlet` called `BeerSelect.java` and I'm getting this error:

```
javac: file not found: BeerSelect.java
```

I compiled using: javac -classpath `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\lib\servlet-api.jar"; -d classes \BeerSelect.java`

I used this command to compile with my current directory set to where the `servlet` is stored, my class path is set correctly.

I checked many related questions on this site and cannot get the answer

Comment: \BeerSelect.java?? use only BeerSelect.java and make sure that file is in current directory

Comment: when i use BeerSelect it says Directory not found,the file is in the current directory

Comment: why don't you use IDE??

Comment: i am preparing for an oracle web component certification and the book that i'm using uses javac compiler. thanks for your contribution Sachin Verma.

Comment: then i suggest not to use an IDE. More questions come to your mind more you will master.GOOD LUCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set your classpath to point to your JDK bin directory -- instead it should be the PATH environment variable, which serves a different purpose to classpath. (The classpath defines a list of jars and directories containing compiled Java .class code; the PATH variable defines a list of paths where the shell needs to look and locate programs to execute when they are not found in the current directory -- so if you type for instance zip -- it would look in all the directories defined in PATH and figure out that zip program is located under /usr/bin) Secondly if you want to compile sources from both directory you need to specify:

all the paths where the sources are (both home/pathToFolderA/src and home/pathToFolderB/gen-java)
the path where the compiled .class files to be generated
specify in the classpath any library you might use in your source files
To sum it up, it would be something like this to compile:

```
javac -d /home/pathToFolderWithResultsOfCompilation -classpath /path/to/some.jar:/path/to/another.jar home/pathToFolderA/src/*.java home/pathToFolderB/gen-java/*.java
```

and to run your compiled programs:

```
java -classpath /path/to/some.jar:/path/to/another.jar:/home/pathToFolderWithResultsOfCompilation full.name.of.your.Java
```

Comment: topcat3 and Sachin Verma
thank you very much its working now.

Comment: the problem was with javac command, i followed topcat3's javac command templates and its running

Comment: however you solved this problem you should answer it yourself and specify the real problem that you solved, so that any other person that look into this question can get a clear answer.

Comment: The problem was with the path to the folder used to store the results of compilation(.class file) and onether problem was appending "\" to the BeerSelect servlet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the command i was using:
javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\lib\servlet-api.jar"; -d ***classes*** ***\BeerSelect.java***

is with the path name to store the results of compilation (.class file) and putting a backslash on the BeerSelect servlet name (i highlighted the errors).
I refined the command to look like this:

javac -d ***C:\Users\ModernWarFare\Desktop\MyProject\beerV1\classes*** BeerSelect.java

the highlited path is where i'm going to store the .class file and i didn't specify the path to the BeerSelect.java file because it is in the current directory

note that i ommited the path to the servlet-api.jar file because i am using tomcat 7, it already have all the jar files i need stored on C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\lib directory.

Sorry for responding late, i have limited time online